# Why does clearing my hash, also clear my array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :154 > a = []
 => []
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :154 > h = {:test => "test"}
 => {:test=>"test"} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :155 > a << h
 => [{:test=>"test"}] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :156 > h.clear
 => {} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :157 > a
 => [{}]
```

I'm very confused, especially since I can change the elements of the hash without it affecting the array.  But when I clear the hash the array is updated and cleared of its hash contents.  Can someone explain?

Comment: What is `a`? You must be missing something here that you probably typed in your irb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `a << h`, you are really passing the reference of h to a. So when you update h, a also see's those changes because it contains a reference rather than a copy of that value.

In order for it not to change in a, you must pass a cloned value of h into a.

An example would be:

```
a << h.clone
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear with my question.  I wanted to know why this was happening, but also whether there was a way to use clear without it affecting the array, or do I have to manually empty out the hash?

Comment: As seen in my answer, you can clone h(aka make a new reference to the data in h), this way you can clear the hash without it affecting the array.

Comment: Ruby is *not* pass-by-reference. It is pass-by-value. *Always*. No exceptions. As was discussed countless times on the mailinglists, the forums, the blogs, the StackOverflows, the Twitters and who knows where else.

Comment: @Jorg it's more like "pass a reference by value" type semantics, subtle, yet large difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does not make a *copy* of this hash when you add it to the array — it simply stores a *reference* to the original variable. So, when you empty the original variable, the reference stored in the array now refers to the empty hash.

If you want to copy the hash element so this does not occur, use Ruby's `clone` method.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :049 > h = { :test => 'foo' }
 => {:test=>"foo"}
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :050 > a = []
 => [] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :051 > a << h.clone
 => [{:test=>"foo"}] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :052 > h.clear
 => {} 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :053 > a
 => [{:test=>"foo"}]
```